# MYSQL Query Calculation in relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

**MySQL Schema**

```
product_categories: 
id, name

products
id,category_id,name,description

product_offers
id,product_id,name,email

product_offer_negotiations
id,product_offer_id,offer(float),by_user(ENUM-Seller/buyer),status
```

This is there query i have tried...

```
select products.*, 
product_categories.name as category_name, 
COUNT(product_offers.id) AS total_offers, 
ROUND( AVG(product_offer_negotiations.offer), 2) AS avg_offer 
from products 
inner join product_categories on product_categories.id = products.category_id 
inner join product_offers on product_offers.product_id = products.id 
inner join product_offer_negotiations on product_offer_negotiations.product_offer_id = product_offers.id 
and product_offer_negotiations.by_user = ? 
group by products.id;
```

I would like to get all fields from product table, total_offers and avg_offer offer for product (only highest value from negotiation table per offer_id - no duplicatation)

This query only returns first row of products table. Thanks for help.

Comment: Kindly provide some sample data, the result you are getting from the sample data and the expected result from that sample data.